# Find files on a specific sector of a DVD

Tags: iso, optical-media

Is there a tool or way to figure out what file/files are on a specific sector of a DVD?

Sometimes when installing from DVD+R's/DVD-R's I get a "Buffer I/O error" message with a sector number of range of sectors listed in the message. Is there a way to figure out the specific files that are affected? I do have the original `.iso` images from which these discs were created.

**Edit:** See [my previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/33887/backing-up-audit-data-with-growisofs) for details on the Buffer I/O error. If you have any ideas about that please post there. For this question let's ignore *why* my DVDs are bad. :-)

Comment: (RE: your edit) yah, that's why I went ahead and put on there what I could find to help. Figured it was probably way beyond a simple problem but you never know. Dunno how many times I've down long drawn out explanations just to find out it was the IDE cable or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer I/O errors could mean bad media, bad controller or bad drive. Well, could also mean dirty but I've found it to be more media/hardware than dirt on the lens. Usually if it was a problem with your custom media it would be a completely different error message.

As for your question, this might be useful. Its finding files based on a search via sector using ISObuster. -> http://www.isobuster.com/tips.php?tips_page=13

Answer (score 0):

How are you burning the media?  Is it possible to do an MD5 checksum (or some other verification tool)to verify the integrity?  DVD drives are fast enough that it would probably be easier and faster to test the entire disk instead of searching for the possible defective sectors.

Comment: We've been working on this problem for over a year. Suffice it to say, we've tried EVERYTHING. Our physical media tests don't have any discernable correlation with buffer I/O errors. But if you have any ideas please see my previous question. :-)